# SQL get the time when user access the most

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

We have a list of page url and dateTime record on database.

Is it possible to get the hour where user have access it the most?
The column time displays what time users have access the url the most.

The expected result should look like these:

```
page URL  | # visitor per day |        Date        | Max visitor/hour| time 
----------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------
www.url1  |        49         |   07/07/2017       |       23        | 12:00 - 13:00 
www.url2  |        88         |   07/07/2017       |       39        | 7:00 - 8:00
```

Comment: provide more info, are you looking to query the max visitors per date or the most popular time for all dates combined?

Comment: @Tik Thank you for responding. I was looking for both. On the 2nd column of the table above, should display the max visitor per day. and on the 4th column would be the max visitor on the specific 1 hr range of the day. (e.i from **12:00 - 13:00 ,  23** visitors have access the url1 on the same day, as per table 7-7-17)

Comment: @Tik the column time should be divided into these parts. 00:00 - 00:59 , 1:00 - 1:59 , 2:00 - 2:59 and so on.. and the value that will be displayed on these column should be the time where user have access it the most.

Answer (score 0):

In Subquery get the max hour per each URL and day.
Then join that to the main table, to get the required records.
If you need max hour irrespective of day, then just drop Date column from sub query and the join condition.

```
select *
from maintable
join 
( select pageURL, Date, max(MaxVisitorPerHour) as maxhour
  from table
  group by pageURL, Date) subq
on 
(maintable.pageURL=subq.pageURL AND maintable.Date=subq.Date and     
maintable.maxVisitorPerHour=subq.maxhour)
```